# How to use nom to gobble a string until a delimiter or the end?

Tags: rust, parser-combinators, nom

I'm learning nom, and as a test example I'm trying to parse a string until a delimiter. If my delimiter is `/`, then I want to match everything until that delimiter. For that, a parser like this works:

```rust
named!(gobbledygook, take_until!("/"));
```

I also want to match a string that ends before that delimiter, so I want both `foo/bar` and `foo` to return "foo". I can't seem to find anything suitable in the [list of parsers and combinators](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/e99f9e0e7e8ba5670ecc4c0dc89b1d90ff7ba865/doc/choosing_a_combinator.md).

I guess it would be possible to scan for either the delimiter or the end of the string, but it seems this is such a common case that there should be something obvious that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `take_while!` macro. This code:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

use nom::types::CompleteStr

named!(gobbledygook<CompleteStr, CompleteStr>,
    take_while!(|ch| ch != '/')
);

fn main() {
    println!("1: {}", gobbledygook(CompleteStr("foo/bar")).unwrap().1);
    println!("2: {}", gobbledygook(CompleteStr("foo")).unwrap().1);
}
```

prints:

```
1: foo
2: foo
```

Note that you need to use `CompleteStr` to tell nom that `foo` is the full string (ie. there is no risk the full string is actually `foofoo/bar` in which cas the returned value would be different). See this document for details about `CompleteStr`: https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/master/doc/upgrading_to_nom_4.md#dealing-with-incomplete-usage

Comment: Thanks, got it to work with this. Or well, I had to use CompleteByteSlice since I'm using bytes rather than strings.