# How to use nom to parse until a string is found?

Tags: rust, nom

It's easy to use nom to parse a string until a character is found. [How to use nom to gobble a string until a delimiter or the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009610/how-to-gobble-a-string-until-a-delimiter-or-the-end-with-rust-nom) deals with this.

How do I do the same with a string (multiple characters) instead of a single delimiter?

For example, to parse `abchello`, I want to parse everything until `hello` is found.

Answer (score 1):

[take_until](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/bytes/complete/fn.take_until.html) parse everything up to the provided string, excluded.

```
use nom::{bytes::complete::take_until, IResult};

fn parser(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    take_until("hello")(s)
}

fn main() {
    let result = parser("abchello");
    assert_eq!(Ok(("hello", "abc")), result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code returns the correct result.

```
use nom::{IResult, bytes::complete::is_not};

fn parser(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  is_not("hello")(s)
}

fn main() {
    let result = parser("abchello");
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

The documentation is [here](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/bytes/complete/fn.is_not.html).

```
cargo run
-> Ok(("hello", "abc"))
```

Comment: This is wrong. "The parser will return the longest slice till one of the characters of the combinator’s argument are met.". `parser("abch123");` gives `Ok(("h123", "abc"))`